# How customize command line with icons inside a specific command?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, icons

I know it is possible to customize command line prompt with icons editing bash_profile file. In this case, I want place an icon when it is printed "Password:(icon here) " on command line when you type "sudo something".

Comment: what icons do you mean, can you provide an example? As far as I know terminal should not be able to do so and if it does, I would guess it is just an emoji from unicode

Comment: Some terminals (e.g., iTerm 2 on macOS) provide support for displaying arbitrary graphic files. Even then, emoji are easier to work with.

Comment: I don't believe this has an easy solution as in solution that does not require to change `sudo`'s source code. Nevertheless this question probably belongs on Unix and Linux StackExchange or on SuperUser one, people there might know more

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. Anyway , I would be happy using a simple emoji from unicode @Ordoshsen. Can you explain me how can I do so? Put a emoji next to sudo's "Password: " output?

Comment: @chepner , so, how can I do that? I'm look on Hyper terminal to do something similar (to those, iTerm2...). Thanks

Comment: @mljistcart you would need to go to https://www.sudo.ws/ and download source code for sudo, find the passage where it prompts you for password and rewrite the call to printf or whatever function shows the text in terminal. Sorry, but I won't find it for you, that is maybe a little too complicated, but if you use `find` or really dwell into the source code (with a little C knowledge) you just might find it.

Comment: @Ordoshsen thanks to your suggestion!! I finally discovered a way to do this! I'm very grateful for your reference to sudo source code. There , we can read:

  802:   --with-passprompt="PASSWORD PROMPT"
  803   Default prompt to use when asking for a password; can be overridden
  804   via the -p option and the SUDO_PROMPT environment variable. Supports
  805   the "%H", "%h", "%U" and "%u" escapes as documented in the sudo
  806:  manual page.  The default value is "Password:".
  807   Sudoers option: passprompt

Comment: @mljistcart wow now I feel stupid for not checking man pages. Maybe consider writing and accepting an answer to your own question so people can find the solution more easily